# Cannot find Login view linked by @login_required decorator

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have my login.html but when I am using

```
from flask.ext.login import login_required,LoginManager
```

@login_required decorator generate **another view** that I can't find anywhere in my app or template folder.

```
@app.route('/result/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def result():
    #do something after pass authentication
    return jsonify({'data': 'Passed' })
```

Therefore, after I key in correct login info, I also cannot pass the authentication.

May I know how can I modified the view page that linked by @login_required decorator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can include 
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
If this is not included, it will direct to unauthorized page.

You may refer to [Flask Login quickstart for OpenShift](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-openshift-quickstart)

Comment: my case is the login manager library some sort of corrupted, but after I start the login_manager from scratch as what you suggested to refer, I did it, thanks